# How do I find 4 complementary 24bit RGB colors with no overlapping bits?

Tags: rust, colors, bit-manipulation, rgb, maze

I am seeking four colors that are distinguishable, somewhat complementary/visually appealing, and share no bits in common. What I mean by this is as follows:

- Consider only the first 24 bits of a u32 and use them to represent an RGB color.
- Select four colors in this manner.
- The colors should have no bits in common for the following bitwise properties.

For example, if we treat these colors as unique identifiers then we should be able to mix these colors in interesting ways in a unsigned 32 bit integer. `COLOR_1` would represent a different color than `COLOR_1 | COLOR_2`, and so on. Each of the four colors is unique and every possible combination is unique.

However, I have the additional constraint that no two bits among these four colors should overlap. That means if we have the following u32 `let mix: u32 = COLOR_1 | COLOR_2 | COLOR_3;`, then the following operation should be true: `(mix & !COLOR_1) == COLOR_2 | COLOR_3`. This is equivalent to removing `COLOR_1` from the integer without affecting any bits belonging to `COLOR_2` and `COLOR_3`.

I thought exploring all possible [tetrads](https://www.paletton.com/wiki/index.php/Tetradic_color_scheme#:%7E:text=A%20tetrad%20is%20a%20color,clear%20dominance%20of%20one%20color.) would be a good start (here is picture of a tetrad as well represented by the four points on this circle). However, I am not sure how to appropriately explore the RGB color space for a solution to my problem.

[image]

Is there a way to get something close to a tetrad with the properties I am looking for? Or maybe there is another color theory approach? The requirements overall are as follows:

- 4 RGB colors represented in the low order 24 bits of a u32 such that no two colors share any bits in common.
- Colors that are close to tetradic points that have a 90 degree angle towards each other. This is not a strict requirement as I am only seeking four colors that are easily distinguishable from one another with the bitwise properties from point 1.
- Luminance is not a great concern but the colors should be visible against a black background.

Update: I removed my code as it incorrectly sought a solution and distracts from the great answer provided below.

Comment: I'm not sure if I have understood what you are trying to do, but can't you use (0b111111 << 3), (0b111111 << 2), and so on?

Comment: I agree I could pick some bits that satisfy the property I'm looking for but I liked the idea of a set of 4 colors having a visually appealing/logical relationship. In this case a tetrad ensures that no one color dominates and they compliment each other nicely. Some tetrads I looked at can also be more accessible because the colors are more easily distinguishable. But tetrads are just the first thing I found when I started looking into this topic so maybe there are other ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems surprisingly tricky, mathematically. Am I understanding you right that you're looking for 4 colors which:

- Bit-anding two of the colors in byte-based RGB is always 0
- Have a 90° (or 180°) angle towards each other in HSL color space
- The colors should be colorful / have high chroma (i.e. luminosity 0.5 and saturation 1 in HSL)

The first is a hard requirement, the second and third probably not so much.

I don't know how to come up with a set of such colors. You could brute-force this, as there's "only" ~10¹⁶·⁸ possibilities, but let's try something more interesting:

You can randomly generate a set of 4 colors by just taking 24 1-bits and randomly assigning them to one of the 4 colors:

```
fn generate_candidate(&mut self) -> [u32; 4] {
    let mut rng = thread_rng();
    let mut colorbits = [0u32; 4];
    for i in 0..24 {
        *colorbits.choose_mut(&mut rng).unwrap() |= 1 << i;
    }
    colorbits
}
// Yeah, this can't generate all possible combinations, it'll never have less than 24 1-bits. I don't think having less is useful.
```

You can also generate a new similar candidate from an existing one by taking one bit and moving it to a different color

```
fn tweak_candidate(&mut self, candidate: &[u32; 4]) -> [u32; 4] {
    let mut rng = thread_rng();
    let mut new = candidate.clone();
    let bit = rng.gen_range(0..24);
    // unset bit everywhere
    for c in &mut new {
        *c = *c & !(1 << bit);
    }
    // set bit in randomly chosen color
    *new.choose_mut(&mut rng).unwrap() |= 1 << bit;
    new
}
```

This is enough to allow walking through the space of possible colors quadruples. To find a good quadruples on that walk, you need to define what a good quadruples is, but you would have also had to do the same for brute-forcing:

```
fn rank_candidate(&mut self, candidate: &[u32; 4]) -> f64 {
    let rgbs =
        candidate.map(|bits| Rgb::from(<[u8; 3]>::try_from(&bits.to_be_bytes()[1..]).unwrap()));
    let hsls = rgbs.clone().map(|rgb| Hsl::from(rgb));
    let mut hues = hsls.clone().map(|c| c.hue());
    hues.sort_by(f64::total_cmp);
    let angles: [f64; 3] = array::from_fn(|i| (hues[i + 1] - hues[i]));
    - angles.map(|a| (a - 90.).powf(2.)).into_iter().sum::<f64>() 
    - hsls
        .map(|c| (100. - c.saturation()).powf(2.) + (100. - c.lightness() * 2.).powf(2.))
        .iter()
        .sum::<f64>() * 0.1;
}
```

And with that, you can apply a metaheuristic like simulated annealing to find you a nice set of colors.

[Full code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=87f70a9d02bbf7e9a11405f674a57f6e)

Interestingly, it seems that the conditions about bits and angle limits the luminosity to ~0.25.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for and I tested some of the colors and they indeed have the desired properties and many combinations look great as they overlap or remove themselves from a color square, thank you! You are correct the highest priority is no overlapping bits. I just thought a tetradic would be a good place to start because 4 colors that have a 90 degree angle towards each other were "generally" easy to tell apart. The luminosity limit is actually fine for my use case. As more of the four colors mix the colors lighten in interesting ways.